# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined even after all proper Binding for WebRTC and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, state

I am getting the following error,

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
at Socket.eval (CommunicationContainer.js?41c1:40)
at Socket.Emitter.emit (index.js?7297:133)
at Socket.onevent (socket.js?2851:278)
at Socket.onpacket (socket.js?2851:236)
at Manager.eval (index.js?40de:21)
at Manager.Emitter.emit (index.js?7297:133)
at Manager.ondecoded (manager.js?78eb:345)
at Decoder.eval (index.js?40de:21)
at Decoder.Emitter.emit (index.js?7297:133)
at Decoder.add (index.js?568d:251)
"
```

Through all I've looked up this is because the binding is not properly done inside the constructor, however after everything I've done as far as I can tell I have all proper bindings and have no idea why this error is occurring. The error says it occurs in the CommmunicationContainer which I have attached here

**Communication Container**

```
import React from 'react'
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import Remarkable from 'remarkable-react'
import MediaContainer from './MediaContainer'
import Communication from '../components/Communication'
import store from '../store/configureStore'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


class CommunicationContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sid: '',
      message: '',
      audio: true,
      video: true
    };

    this.handleInvitation = this.handleInvitation.bind(this);
    this.handleHangup = this.handleHangup.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.toggleVideo = this.toggleVideo.bind(this);
    this.toggleAudio = this.toggleAudio.bind(this);
    this.send = this.send.bind(this);
    this.hideAuth = this.hideAuth.bind(this);
    this.full = this.full.bind(this);
  }

  hideAuth() {
    this.props.media.setState({bridge: 'connecting'});
  }
  full() {
    this.props.media.setState({bridge: 'full'});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Comments componentDidMount: ');
    console.log(this);
    const socket = this.props.socket;
    console.log('props', this.props)
    this.setState({video: this.props.video, audio: this.props.audio});

    socket.on('create', () =>
      this.props.media.setState({user: 'host', bridge: 'create'}));
    socket.on('full', this.full);
    socket.on('bridge', role => this.props.media.init());
    socket.on('join', () =>
      this.props.media.setState({user: 'guest', bridge: 'join'}));
    socket.on('approve', ({ message, sid }) => {
      this.props.media.setState({bridge: 'approve'});
      this.setState({ message, sid });
    });
    socket.emit('find');
    this.props.getUserMedia
      .then(stream => {
          this.localStream = stream;
          this.localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = this.state.video;
          this.localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = this.state.audio;
        });
  }
  handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.dataset.ref]: e.target.value});
  }
  send(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.socket.emit('auth', this.state);
    this.hideAuth();
  }
  handleInvitation(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.socket.emit([e.target.dataset.ref], this.state.sid);
    this.hideAuth();
  }
  getContent(content) {
    return {__html: (new Remarkable()).render(content)};
  }
  toggleVideo() {
    const video = this.localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !this.state.video;
    this.setState({video: video});
    this.props.setVideo(video);
  }
  toggleAudio() {
    const audio = this.localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = !this.state.audio;
    this.setState({audio: audio});
    this.props.setAudio(audio);
  }
  handleHangup() {
    this.props.media.hangup();
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.media);
    return (
      <Communication

        {...this.state}
        toggleVideo={this.toggleVideo}
        toggleAudio={this.toggleAudio}
        getContent={this.getContent}
        send={this.send}
        handleHangup={this.handleHangup}
        handleInput={this.handleInput}
        handleInvitation={this.handleInvitation} />
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = store => ({video: store.video, audio: store.audio});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    setVideo: boo => store.dispatch({type: 'SET_VIDEO', video: boo}),
    setAudio: boo => store.dispatch({type: 'SET_AUDIO', audio: boo})
  }
);

CommunicationContainer.propTypes = {
  socket: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getUserMedia: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  audio: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  video: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  setVideo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setAudio: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  media: PropTypes.instanceOf(MediaContainer)
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CommunicationContainer);
```

I've included the other Containers and Components for reference in case the error has something to do with them, but as far as is being shown the error is within the CommunicationContainer with the state being undefined at the socket line. As well I have included the error image. 
This application is a WebRTC React page within a React website where the user sets the room ID and upon pressing the button launches into the room. 
[The Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFLch.png)
[The Error Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myazS.png)

**Chat Room Page**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MediaContainer from './MediaContainer'
import CommunicationContainer from './CommunicationContainer'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../store/configureStore'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

class ChatRoomPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true
    }).catch(e => alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name))
    this.socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8080');

  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.addRoom();
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.socket);
    console.log(this.getUserMedia);
    console.log(this.media);

      return (
        <div>
        <MediaContainer media={media => this.media = media} socket={this.socket} getUserMedia={this.getUserMedia} />
        <CommunicationContainer socket={this.socket} media={this.media} getUserMedia={this.getUserMedia} />

              <h1>AppointmentSetup</h1>
          </div>
      );
  }
}

//commented out

const mapStateToProps = store => ({rooms: new Set([...store.rooms])});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => (
    {
      addRoom: () => store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ROOM', room: ownProps.match.params.room })
    }
  );
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChatRoomPage);
```

**Media Container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

class MediaBridge extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bridge: '',
      user: ''
    }
    this.onRemoteHangup = this.onRemoteHangup.bind(this);
    this.onMessage = this.onMessage.bind(this);
    this.sendData = this.sendData.bind(this);
    this.setupDataHandlers = this.setupDataHandlers.bind(this);
    this.setDescription = this.setDescription.bind(this);
    this.sendDescription = this.sendDescription.bind(this);
    this.hangup = this.hangup.bind(this);
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.setDescription = this.setDescription.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    // chrome polyfill for connection between the local device and a remote peer
    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    this.props.media(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserMedia
      .then(stream => this.localVideo.srcObject = this.localStream = stream);
    this.props.socket.on('message', this.onMessage);
    this.props.socket.on('hangup', this.onRemoteHangup);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.media(null);
    if (this.localStream !== undefined) {
      this.localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
    }
    this.props.socket.emit('leave');
  }
  onRemoteHangup() {
    this.setState({user: 'host', bridge: 'host-hangup'});
  }
  onMessage(message) {
      if (message.type === 'offer') {
          // set remote description and answer
          this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
          this.pc.createAnswer()
            .then(this.setDescription)
            .then(this.sendDescription)
            .catch(this.handleError); // An error occurred, so handle the failure to connect

      } else if (message.type === 'answer') {
          // set remote description
          this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
      } else if (message.type === 'candidate') {
          // add ice candidate
          this.pc.addIceCandidate(
              new RTCIceCandidate({
                  sdpMLineIndex: message.mlineindex,
                  candidate: message.candidate
              })
          );
      }
  }
  sendData(msg) {
    this.dc.send(JSON.stringify(msg))
  }
  // Set up the data channel message handler
  setupDataHandlers() {
      this.dc.onmessage = e => {
          var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
          console.log('received message over data channel:' + msg);
      };
      this.dc.onclose = () => {
        this.remoteStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
        console.log('The Data Channel is Closed');
      };
  }
  setDescription(offer) {
    this.pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
  }
  // send the offer to a server to be forwarded to the other peer
  sendDescription() {
    this.props.socket.send(this.pc.localDescription);
  }
  hangup() {
    this.setState({user: 'guest', bridge: 'guest-hangup'});
    this.pc.close();
    this.props.socket.emit('leave');
  }
  handleError(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  init() {
    // wait for local media to be ready
    const attachMediaIfReady = () => {
      this.dc = this.pc.createDataChannel('chat');
      this.setupDataHandlers();
      console.log('attachMediaIfReady')
      this.pc.createOffer()
        .then(this.setDescription)
        .then(this.sendDescription)
        .catch(this.handleError); // An error occurred, so handle the failure to connect
    }
    // set up the peer connection
    // this is one of Google's public STUN servers
    // make sure your offer/answer role does not change. If user A does a SLD
    // with type=offer initially, it must do that during  the whole session
    this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers: [{url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]});
    // when our browser gets a candidate, send it to the peer
    this.pc.onicecandidate = e => {
        console.log(e, 'onicecandidate');
        if (e.candidate) {
            this.props.socket.send({
                type: 'candidate',
                mlineindex: e.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                candidate: e.candidate.candidate
            });
        }
    };
    // when the other side added a media stream, show it on screen
    this.pc.onaddstream = e => {
        console.log('onaddstream', e)
        this.remoteStream = e.stream;
        this.remoteVideo.srcObject = this.remoteStream = e.stream;
        this.setState({bridge: 'established'});
    };
    this.pc.ondatachannel = e => {
        // data channel
        this.dc = e.channel;
        this.setupDataHandlers();
        this.sendData({
          peerMediaStream: {
            video: this.localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled
          }
        });
        //sendData('hello');
    };
    // attach local media to the peer connection
    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => this.pc.addTrack(track, this.localStream));
    // call if we were the last to connect (to increase
    // chances that everything is set up properly at both ends)
    if (this.state.user === 'host') {
      this.props.getUserMedia.then(attachMediaIfReady);
    }
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.media);
    console.log(this.getUserMedia)
    return (
      <div className={`media-bridge ${this.state.bridge}`}>
        <video className="remote-video" ref={(ref) => this.remoteVideo = ref} autoPlay></video>
        <video className="local-video" ref={(ref) => this.localVideo = ref} autoPlay muted></video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
MediaBridge.propTypes = {
  socket: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getUserMedia: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  media: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
export default MediaBridge;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I don't see any binding issues within this yet continue to get the error no matter what I try.

Comment: You're doing it wrong way. You have to use `setState` in the parent component not child component.

Comment: What do you mean? I have the chat application in a separate application on its own and it works fine, so I don't get why it's creating this issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Those methods have not bin bind on your controller and you are calling them from other methods , it may be the reason!
 `hideAuth()
  full()`